# Ajax in plugin fails - but only on one blog - no idea why

Tags: functions, ajax, javascript

this seems hard to understand. I created a plugin, and it works fine on different installations of me and a few other blogs.

But on one blog of someone else it fails. After getting through debugs and console entries, I believe I found the source of the failure:

At some step of the process the plugin calls a function with ajax:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var data = {
               'action': 'mp_throwcontent_2',
               'MedioPay_postid': mp_mypostid,
            'MedioPay_outputs': mp_outputs,
            'MedioPay_number': mp_numberof_payments,
            'MedioPay_userID': mp_userID,
            'Mediopay_newCounter': mp_newCounter,
            'MedioPay_firstPartner': mp_firstPartner,
            'MedioPay_secondPartner': mp_secondPartner,
            'MedioPay_thirdPartner': mp_thirdPartner,
                'MedioPay_fourthPartner': mp_fourthPartner,
                'MedioPay_shareQuote': mp_sharing,
                'MedioPay_preview': mp_preview
             };
        console.log("turning data over");
          jQuery.post(my_ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
          console.log("unlock 2 " + response);
              mp_unlockContent2(payment, response);
           });
       });
```

Then a function is called:

```
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mp_throwcontent_2', 'mp_throwcontent_2' );

function mp_throwcontent_2() {
   // some ifs and so on 
   // echo "output"
}
```

When the plugin starts, Ajax is localized

```
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

A little quirk: I localized it twice, accidently, here too:

```
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );
```

Can this be a problem?

All this works very fine on a few blogs. But in one the operations just stop when the ajax starts. No error, nothing in debug, it just stops.

Does anybody have an idea what I can do to make it run? Is there a fallback to call in case it fails?

Ah, and to make it even weirder: The plugin worked fine on that blog, but suddenly it stopped working, while the owners tells me he didn't even change anything on his wordpress installation.

Comment: I see your `jQuery.post` has no failure/error handler, can you add one to see what the error was so we're not guessing? I also saw you're using the old admin ajax handler for AJAX, rather than making AJAX requests to the modern more reliable REST API, was there a specific reason? Note that you'll need to consult the jQuery docs for how to handle failures when making HTTP requests. Did you check your PHP error log? Also is the user logged in? If this were the REST API it would just tell you the issue in an error message in the response, but Admin AJAX can be cryptic

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't know about the rest api and am currently investigating to use it instead of Ajax. Sound like a good idea but also some work. We tested it both logged in and not. Have to to research how to add an error handler

Comment: In all honesty, a basic rest endpoint is trivial to add, and the  javascript part is nearly identical,  instead of POST'ing to `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` you  POST  to `/wp-json/yournamespace/v1/yourendpoint`, then in the handler you return rather than echo the response, look up the `register_rest_route`  function

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged into one of the sites? `wp_ajax_nopriv_` hooks will not fire if the user is logged in, so if you've only used that hook, the AJAX request will not work at all if you are logged in.

You will need to hook both `wp_ajax_nopriv_mp_throwcontent_2` and `wp_ajax_mp_throwcontent_2` for it to work with both logged in and logged out users.

Comment: Mh, when it works it works if logged in or not. In this case it doesn't work either.

Comment: It's literally impossible for it to work if you're logged in unless you use both hooks. Look at the source of admin-ajax.php

Answer (score 0):

Byusing the ancient admin AJAX API, the only error information you can get from the response is either a HTTP error code, or a `0`, neither of which are particularly  helpful.

So first, lets actually handle the failure in jQuery so we know when it's failed:

```js
jQuery.post(my_ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
  console.log("unlock 2 " + response);
  mp_unlockContent2(payment, response);
}).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)  {
    //  it failed!
    console.log( errorThrown );
} );
```

Now we can see what the AJAX request contained if it failed

Next, lets swap this:

```php
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mp_throwcontent_2', 'mp_throwcontent_2' );

function mp_throwcontent_2() {
   // some ifs and so on 
   // echo "output"
}
```

For this:

```php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'add_custom_users_api');

function add_custom_users_api(){
    register_rest_route( 'bergmann/v1', '/throwcontent', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'mp_throwcontent_2',
    ));
}

function mp_throwcontent_2( $request ) {
    $response = '';
    // use $request['stuff'] instead of  $_POST['stuff']
    // otherwise put all the relevant stuff in $response
    return $response;
}
```

Now we have a URL at `yoursite.com/wp-json/bergmann/v1/throwcontent`, and if we make a `GET` request  (  e.g. with `jQuery.get` or visiting it in a browser ), we'll get  `$response` in JSON form.

So lets updatethe localized script:

```php
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
    [
        'endpoint_url' => rest_url( '/bergmann/v1/throwcontent' ),
        'we_value'     => 1234
    ]
);
```

Then update our JS code:

```js
jQuery.post(
  my_ajax_object.endpoint_url,
  data,
  function(response) {
    const reply = JSON.parse( response );
    console.log("unlock 2 " + reply );
    mp_unlockContent2(payment, reply);
  }
).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)  {
    //  it failed!
    console.log( errorThrown );
} );
```

Some notes:

- Indent indent indent, and be consistent, a good editor will do it for you, and it avoids so many types of bug
- If you're getting stuff, `GET` stuff, don't `POST` unless you're sending data
- Admin AJAX is old, very old, if you make a mistake in the REST API it will just tell you in english in the response. E.g. if you request an endpoint that doesn't exist, it says so, but Admin AJAX will give you a `0` mystery reply
- Your original problem is probably related to only doing `nopriv`, if you'd used the REST API it would have just told you that, rather than making you guess
- If you want parameters to send, you can add them during `register_rest_route`, and WP will do all the checking and sanitising and validating for you
- Ideally you want to ditch `jQuery` in favour of the more modern `fetch` and a polyfill for old browsers, or at least `jQuery.ajax`
- Always handle the errors, don't just make the request then scratch your head when it doesn't succeed, add the failure/error handlers! The worst that happens is you get a helpful error message

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It will help me a lot. 

Meanwhile, I listened to other advices and tried the REST API, hoping it to be more stable. It was actually very easy to migrate the code.